# How to prove this matrix is not singular

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank

My goal is to prove that $\det(A) \neq 0$, I took this statement as to be be true because comes from a scientific paper (see below).

Define $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2k \times 2k} $ to be:

$$
     A = \begin{bmatrix}
         x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^k & y_1 x_1 & y_1 x_1^2 & \cdots y_1 x_1^k \\
         x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^k & y_2 x_2 & y_2 x_2^2 & \cdots y_2 x_2^k \\
         \vdots \\ 
         x_{2k} & x_{2k}^2 & \cdots & x_{2k}^k & y_{2k} x_{2k} & y_{2k} x_{2k}^2 & \cdots y_{2k} x_{2k}^k \\
     \end{bmatrix}
$$

where all the $x_i$'s are distinct and different from 0, $x_i \neq y_i$ and not all $y_i$ values are equals. Additionally, there is a polynomial $S$ of degree $2k$ such that $y_i = S(i)$ for every i.

I looked similar proofs based on Vandermonde matrix and Kronecker product, but I can't get to a demonstration.

#### More context about this demonstration

I am trying to prove Lemma 1 of [Distributed oblivious transfer](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2414100_Distributed_Oblivious_Transfer).

Given two inputs $m_0, m_1$, define
$$
Q(x,y) = \sum_{j=0}^{d_x} \sum_{l=0}^{d_y} a_{j,l} x^j y^l
$$
where $a_{0,0} = m_0$ and $\sum_{l=0}^{d_y} a_{0,l} = m_1$.

I want to show that retrieving $k=2 d_x + 1$ values doesn't allow to learn more than a single linear combination of $m_0$ and $m_1$.

The beginning of the proof is detailed in the proof of Lemma 1, I am stuck at proving that the matrix $B'$ is not singular.

Comment: Are you curve-fitting a rational polynomial?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou No, the purpose of the demonstration is to show that a certain set of values is not enough to learn information about a bivariate polynomial coefficients

Comment: I suppose there can be cases where the $y_i x_i^k$ columns are **not** linearly independent from the $x_i^k$ columns. For example when all the $y_i$ values are constant (the same).

Comment: is this a true result that you are just trying recreate the proof or is it something you are conjecturing ? Either way, I think partitioning this into $4$ Vandermonde-like matrices of $k\times k$ sizes and use the block matrix determinant formula would be a start.

Comment: $A$ is singular when $k\ge2$ and $y_i=x_i$ for each $i$.

Comment: If this is true, then:
$$P(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^{2k}\alpha_i(1+y_{i})\sum_{j=1}^kx_i^j$$ has a real zero satisfying your constraints iff $\alpha_i=0,$ which seems like a really strong conclusion.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou We assume $y_i$ values are not  equals

Comment: @user1551 you're right, I added an assumption about that too.

Comment: @dezdichado I'm not sure to get it all, can you add some details ?

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily singular. Pick two monic degree-$k$ polynomials $p(x)=\sum_{r=1}^kc_rx^r$ and $q(x)=\sum_{r=1}^kd_rx^r$ with zero constant terms at random. More often than not, we have $q(x_i)\ne0$ for every $i$ and $\frac{p(x_1)}{q(x_1)},\ldots,\frac{p(x_{2k})}{q(x_{2k})}$ are all distinct. Now let $y_i=-\frac{p(x_i)}{q(x_i)}$. Then $A$ is singular. In fact, $Av=0$ when $v=(c_1,\ldots,c_k,d_1,\ldots,d_k)^T\ne0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right and I edited the question. After re-reading the paper, there is a constraint preventing this, although stated very far away from the proof. It appears $y_i$ is defined using a polynomial $S$ of degree $2k$, such that $y_i = S(x_i)$ for every $x_i$. There is even a sentence in the paper that states that if the degree of $S$ is less than $2k$ the security might be affected, thanks for proving why.